# Evaluating fuzzy C-Means clustering

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering

I am new machine learning practitioner. I have run fuzzy c-means algorithm on a multi-label dataset ([PPI dataset](https://snap.stanford.edu/node2vec/Homo_sapiens.mat)) on the network using [skfuzzy](https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/) python library. I want to evaluate the performance of the fuzzy c-means algorithm on the dataset using overlapped NMI, Omega Index. I found a github repository [OvpNMI](https://github.com/eXascaleInfolab/OvpNMI), but it requires two clsfiles, ground truth labels file and predicted labels file. I created a truth labels file from dataset but unable to get the predicted labels file from the c-means library. What I am able to get from [cmean_predict](https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/api/skfuzzy.cluster.html?highlight=cmean#skfuzzy.cluster.cmeans_predict) is fuzzy c-partitioned matrix. I have searched the internet but failed to get answers. Can anyone please help me?